# Layout different in LIVE

Tags: change-set

We have just moved the changeset to LIVE instance. But when viewing the opportunities (for example) it seems the layout is different to that of the development instnace. I had first imported the custom fields and then the profiles in a separate changeset but still it seems not to work. How to fix this?

Looking into the Field accessibility the properties are different to that of DEV I.E. in live itis seen as hidden but in dev it is visible....can this be imported via changeset? please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To import field permissions, include the field and profiles in a single change set. The security permissions will be migrated when you do that.

Comment: Thk u....it worked

Comment: We have updated some std picklist values....how to import those? any advise?

Comment: @PrabhuSethupathy unfortunately, that's not possible. Please, update those manually